# How to create deployment links in a Github PR?

Tags: github, deployment, travis-ci

I've noticed Github allows linking to deployments:

[image]

I currently have Travis CI doing automatic builds on new PRs and deploying the artifacts to `transfer.sh`. How could I get such a link to `View deployment` to show up in my Github PR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `environment_url` field when POST'ing the deployment status.

Additionally, you need to use the `application/vnd.github.ant-man-preview+json` Content-Type header as it's still a developer preview feature.

More info:

- It's mentioned in the API docs https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/deployments/#create-a-deployment-status
- https://developer.github.com/changes/2016-04-06-deployment-and-deployment-status-enhancements/#link-to-a-live-deployment